# Is it possible the create a pkg that doesn't require root access (user & password prompt)

Tags: applications, password, permission, pkg

The title says it all really, is it possible to create a pkg that can install without the user requiring to enter their password?

Comment: What payload are you looking to install? If it's any type of application, or something that will be installed system-wide, the password will be required.

Comment: @tubedogg It is an app bound for `/Applications`, but the pre-install script downloads a `tar.gz` to `/tmp` then extracts it to there - so I don't know if that makes a difference. Does the same apply for a dmg copy type of install?

Comment: @tubedogg with PackageMaker I can't even seem to put a png into my home directory without it prompting me for my password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in PackageMaker.

You can still install into `/Applications` too, but the user would need to be in the `admin` group because the default permissions for `/Applications` are `drwxrwxr-x+ 90 root  admin`, so as long as the user is in `admin` then they'll have write permissions.

[image]

Comment: Hm like with most things in PackageMaker this seems a little buggy. This seems to work on 10.6.8, but I just tried to use that installer on 10.8.4 and it was still prompting

Comment: Yea I think something was changed in 10.7 - in 10.7 and onwards the pkg Installer seems to prompt for root regardless of what you do. Installing on a pre-10.7 os it seems to respect this option and not prompt. I don't know if it's a bug or a security fix or what, but on 10.7 onwards I don't think there's a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can't install into `~/Applications` without admin access and password. In 10.7 and onward Apple changed permissions so even admins need password to install into `/Applications`, whether using installer or drag and drop.